# I don't know how put distance between buttons

Tags: java

I want to put space between buttons:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJMB8.png]

I want to put the buttons in the center, one below the other with distance between them, I apologize if my code is messy, I want to do something more complicated, it is only a prototype, plus you do not know so well Java GUI so accepted criticism

**Class first:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class first {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        second ob = new second();
        ob.setLocation(500, 100);
        ob.setSize(500, 500);
        ob.setVisible(true);
        ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

**Class second:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Formatter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.text.Position;
import java.util.*;


public class second extends JFrame {
    int i;
    private JPanel pan1;
    private JPanel pan2;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JTextArea tx;
    private JButton[] buton = new JButton[50];
    private Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    second() {

        pan1 = new JPanel();
        pan1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        pan1.setLocation(0, 0);
        pan1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));

        add(pan1, BorderLayout.NORTH);



        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            buton[i]=new JButton("Button "+i);
            box.add(buton[i]);
        }

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(box);

        Dimension d = new Dimension(box.getComponent(0).getPreferredSize());

        sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(d.height);

        d.height *= 10; // Show at least 10 buttons

        sp.getViewport().setPreferredSize(d);
        add(sp);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030800/space-between-buttons-and-window

Comment: @ElonThan: looks to be a different issue in your proposed duplicate. Camickr's got the solution in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> one below the other with distance between them

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). You can add a `verticalStrut(...)` between each button You use the `Box.CreateVerticalStrut(...)` method for this.

Another approach might be to use a `GridLayout`. You can specify a vertical gap in the grid when you create the layout. Note: using this approach all buttons will be the same size and will fill the space available, in which case you may need to nest the panel with the GridLayout in another panel so the buttons are displayed at a reasonable width.

Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Look at all the classes in the JDK API. Note how they all start with an upper case character.

Comment: I try with GridLayout but I don't know why the frame not open say that progam are finish but I not see any frame

Comment: @cosminciuciu, me either. Changing a layout will not affect the display of the frame. Why not start with just adding the vertical strut. Its a one line change to your for loop.

Comment: to be onest a don't know more java gui ,if you can just be more precise with that vertical strut

Comment: @cosminciuciu, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @ camickr sory but I don't know where  clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved., so if you are good make me a printscreen to know me where give feed back and close this answere

Comment: @cosminciuciu The checkmark is just to the left of the answer (just below the up/down arrows used to upvote/downvote an answer). Many times you will get multiple answers to a question. So you select the checkmark to the left of the answer that best solves the problem.

Comment: @ camickr  Thank you!